# Imposing boundary conditions in a finite element sense

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method

Say we have a PDE which is well posed with the boundary condition $|\nabla u|=r$ ($r$ constant) on $\partial\Omega$, where $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^n$ is uniformly convex.

How would one impose this condition into a finite element algorithm, does it count as a neumann boundary condition? or must we always have a normal derivative.

Comment: It's not Neumann as written. What is the PDE?

Comment: @user7530 It is the monge ampere equation $det(D^2u)=f(x,u,\nabla u)$, the boundary condition is called the "second boundary condition" and it arises in optimal mass transport

Comment: An interesting condition. Consider asking at [scicomp.se], which has a fair number of finite-elementists.